# Custom error text in case of NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, browser

Is there a way to show this error in a given language instead of English:

> Your clock is behind
>   A private connection to www.site.com can't be established because your computer's date and time (Thursday, June 29, 1995 at 12:11:23 AM) are incorrect. NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
>   To establish a secure connection, your clock needs to be set correctly. This is because the certificates that websites use to identify themselves are only valid for specific periods of time. Since your device's clock is incorrect, Chrome cannot verify these certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, that's not possible. The error message is displayed by your browser, complaining, that the connection could not be established and thus no data can be transferred. The only data received by the client is the certificate which gets rejected and the session is terminated so good reasons (certificate can't be established).

The obvious reason is to fix the client's date and time settings. Replacing the mainboard battery and set up NTP or similar services to automatically adjust correct the local time according to remote time servers.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to show this error in a given language instead of English:

How this error is displayed depends fully on the clients browser.

Just imagine the implications if it would be possible to change these kind of messages about failed certificate validation from the server side. In this case one could simply try to reword the warnings so that the client believes everything is fine and will follow a advice to add an exception. This could of course not only be used by proper servers but also by man-in-the-middle attackers and thus lead to easy attacks.